# Running Windows Forms Application (C# .NET 4.0) from batch file with Command Line Arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I'm a Silverlight/ASP.NET developer trying to write my first Windows Forms application to run in the background on a server, populating our database. Eventually would like this to be a Windows service, but it's not required initially.

I need to create a batch file to execute 5 instances of this application, passing in the URL to 5 RESTful endpoints. So I published my app, which created a setup.exe. After installing it, I have an item that points to

`C:\Users\mi2dev\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft\`, with a .appref-ms file.

I'm not sure at this point what to do. Running:

"C:\Users\mi2dev\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft\StreamingApp.appref-ms" -"http://www.myURL.com" throws up a command window briefly, but the app doesn't run, data doesn't populate in DB.

What am I missing here?

Comment: ClickOnce deployment is not appropriate in this case.  You need to copy the executable in a well known location so that you can find it back reliably.  Passing command line arguments is then no longer a problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your application is in .exe format. And make your winform accepts command line arguments (check the main method) also make your Form ctor accepts params too. Then just launch it via cmd line just as you would other command, but here only to navigate to that dir where file exists.

In case of batch, use start command followed by program name and then arguments

Comment: No he does not need to add a parametrized constructor. All .NET console and windows forms application start from the static main method, surely you cannot invoke the form constructor directly from a batch file.

Comment: My Program.cs has string[] args in the constructor. I then pass that argument into my Form.cs constructor. The Program.cs accepts the param from the command line (theoretically). Inside the Main method, it creates an instance of my Form1, passing in the argument. I've thrown a "messagebox.show" inside my Program.cs and it works fine.

Comment: @Davide Piras
You got me wrong there sir. What i meant was, pass arguments to main and then from main to Forms ctor via Application.Run(new Form(..)) :)

Comment: @Scott Silvi
If you can launch your app via a command line (cmd.exe way) like this
$myapplication.exe "this is argument"

And your app launches displaying the arugment as per your messagebox,then the same should work by putting it in batch file using start command

Comment: I don't know where the EXE sits though. I tried to run the exe from my bin\debug folder, but the app throws an error on trying to connect to my database (my connection string code throws a null exception on ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ConnectionString

Comment: How did you tried to run your app? via command line? Did you navigated to that dir using cd <path to bin\Debug> and then launch it.
Does the app works when you run from VS? I am guessing that the connectionstring is in app.config file or some thing and your forgetting it to be copied along with exe.

Comment: @zenwalker, I explained what I meant in my separated answer.

Comment: Copying the app.config did it for me. I had looked at that earlier (found same recommendation when googling), but it was greyed out. I must have been in debug mode without realizing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what is happening inside your application. You need to debug to understand what is going on there when it receives given parameters. 
So I would suggest to debug an `EXE`. For this go to your `EXE` project properties, select `DEBUG` tab in `CommandLineArguments` insert your parameter string. 
Run it in `DEBUG` and hopefully you will figure out a problem.

[image: Screen]

If after debugging it's not yet clear why it behaves in that way, come back to SO :)

Comment: I had to disable "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" to get the command line param to run, but once I did, the application ran fine. Like I said, the App itself is set up fine to run, I'm just not sure how to execute it from batch file

Comment: @Scott, so you say that if you put a command line arguments in this box and run the application it will work?

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how or where to run the app, e.g. "C:\ProgramFiles\MyApp\MyApp.exe" "myURL". I'm not familiar enough with ClickOnce to know what to do here, and googling it did no good :(

Answer (score 1):

Silvi if you plan to use your windows forms application from a batch file and you imagine the applicationm will behave differently in such mode than when opened witha double click, the usual approach is to parse the command line (arguments, also available in the main method as parameter) and to avoid loading the UI at all.

in fact if you have written your application properly the UI only managed the UI and does not contain the whole logic of database manipulation and data transformation.

what you could do is check inside the Main method if there are command line parameters and if you detect any of the special ones you have definded you really avoid to even call `Application.Run(new Form1(...));` and start working in batch mode without user interface.

the same logic you want to use in batch mode or in UI mode can be wrapped in helper classes (often also called business managers or business logic... it depends), so that you do not have code duplication but simply UI or batch will call those classes nicely.

Comment: True in case of special 1s or illegal arguments :)

Comment: At some point I want some UI built in, so I can create some tracking/BI code.